# Display value from selected option on every click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a `dropdown` menu where list is selected from `mysql` database and a `textbox` contain `datepicker`. How can i display value selected from the `dropdown` menu and `datepicker` on every click on add button? The code can add div dynamically `onclick` on add button but the value selected to be displayed in the div are changed on every selected `dropdown` menu because of the `javascript` `onchange` function.

How can i display the value correctly?

```js
$( ".js-datepicker" ).datepicker();

$("#choose_exam").on("change", function() {
  var selected = $(this).val();
  $("#exam").html("" + selected);
});

$("#t_exam").on("change", function() {
  var selected = $(this).val();
  $("#exam_date").html("" + selected);

})

//contents of the div added after clicking on add button in the form
$(".add-more").click(function() {
  var html = $("#copy-fields").html();
  $("#validation-step2").append(html);
  $('.js-datepicker').datepicker('update');
});

//remove button 
$("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
  $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- This is the form contain dropdown menu and datepicker textbox -->
<div class="tab-pane push-30-t push-50" id="validation-step2">

  <div class="form-group">

    <select class="form-control" name="choose_exam[]" id="choose_exam">
    
<!--<?php 
$sql = "Select name from exam_list order by id asc";
$result    = mysql_query( $sql );
while(list($category) = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
$option = '<option value="'.$category.'">'.$category.'</option>';
echo ($option);}
?>-->
    
      <option value="0">Please choose</option>
      <option value="1">Sample Category 1</option>
      <option value="2">Sample Category 2</option>
      <option value="3">Sample Category 3</option>
      <option value="4">Sample Category 4</option>
      <option value="5">Sample Category 5</option>
          </select>

    <label for="choose_exam">Exam List</label>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="js-datepicker form-control" type="text" name="t_exam" id="t_exam" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
    <label for="t_exam">Date</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default add-more pull-right" type="button">Add</button>
  </div>

  <!-- This is for dynamically add every div contains exam and date value upon clicking add button -->

  <div class="copy-fields hide" id="copy-fields">
    <div class="control-group">

      <div class="form-group">
        <div id="exam" name="exam[]"></div>
        <div id="exam_date" name="exam_date[]"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default remove pull-right" type="button">Delete</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Using `jquery ui datepicker` ?

Comment: It's a bootstrap datepicker. I call it from class="js-datepicker"

Comment: [This](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) one?

Comment: Okay, no matter which library using, already you return `t_exam` and `choose_exam` on `change` function but you asking about `on every click on add button`, so you don't want to get on `change` you just want to get on click on add button, right?

Comment: yes, i want to display the selected data on every click on add button

Comment: Your code has several problems that need to be fixed. Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47959068/6313073) for more @newLearner 

Comment: I am wondering what in this question merits 4 upvotes. This is not even clear what the end goal is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

1. The `HTML` you're copying using `var html = $("#copy-fields").html();` contains elements with the `id` attribute specified, which will lead you to having a bunch of elements with the same `id`. Turn `#exam` to `.exam` and `#exam_date` to `.exam_date` to fix that.
2. Then, inside the `change` event, use `first()` or `last()`, so that only the first or the last of `.exam` and `.exam_date` change when the event is triggered. In the first snippet, I use `last()` as in `$(".exam").last().html(this.value);`.
3. The line `$(".js-datepicker").datepicker("update");` throws an error, perhaps because you haven't set which date to update to. In the snippets below, I assume you want to reset it.

**Snippet 1:**

<sup>*(This snippet follows your code as much as possible including a live update of the data 'onchange'.)*</sup>

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */

/* Initialise the datepicker. */
$(".js-datepicker").datepicker();

/* Set the 'change' event. */
$("#choose_exam").on("change", function() {
  $(".exam").last().html(this.value);
});
$("#t_exam").on("change", function() {
  $(".exam_date").last().html(this.value);
})

/* Insert the given data to the DOM. */
$(".add-more").click(function() {
  /* Cache the innerHTML of the '#copy-fields'. */
  var html = $("#copy-fields").html();
  
  /* Insert it as last inside '#validation-step2'. */
  $("#validation-step2").append(html);
  
  /* Reset the 'select' element and the date picker. */
  $("#choose_exam").val(0);
  $(".js-datepicker").val("");
});

/* Remove the saved data when the remove button is clicked. */
$("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
  $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
});
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="tab-pane push-30-t push-50" id="validation-step2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="choose_exam[]" id="choose_exam">
      <option value="0">Please choose</option>
      <option value="1">Sample Category 1</option>
      <option value="2">Sample Category 2</option>
      <option value="3">Sample Category 3</option>
      <option value="4">Sample Category 4</option>
      <option value="5">Sample Category 5</option>
    </select>
    <label for="choose_exam">Exam List</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="js-datepicker form-control" type="text" name="t_exam"
      id="t_exam" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
    <label for="t_exam">Date</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default add-more pull-right" type="button">Add</button>
  </div>

  <!-- This is for dynamically add every div contains exam and date
  value upon clicking add button -->

  <div class="copy-fields hide" id="copy-fields">
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="exam" name="exam[]"></div>
        <div class="exam_date" name="exam_date[]"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default remove pull-right" type="button">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Snippet 2:**

<sup>*(This snippet presents an alternate approach using a template to add the data to the DOM.)*</sup>

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */

/* Create a template. */
var template = `
  <div class="control-group">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="exam" name="exam[]">[_EXAM_]</div>
        <div class="exam_date" name="exam_date[]">[_DATE_]</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default remove pull-right" type="button">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
`;

/* Initialise the datepicker. */
$(".js-datepicker").datepicker();

/* Insert the given data to the DOM. */
$(".add-more").click(function() {
  /* Cache the data. */
  var
    exam = $("#choose_exam").val(),
    date = $("#t_exam").val(),
    editedTemplate = template.replace("[_EXAM_]", exam).replace("[_DATE_]", date);
  
  /* Insert it as last inside '#validation-step2'. */
  $("#validation-step2").append(editedTemplate);
  
  /* Reset the 'select' element and the date picker. */
  $("#choose_exam").val(0);
  $(".js-datepicker").val("");
});

/* Remove the saved data when the remove button is clicked. */
$("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
  $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
});
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="tab-pane push-30-t push-50" id="validation-step2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="choose_exam[]" id="choose_exam">
      <option value="0">Please choose</option>
      <option value="1">Sample Category 1</option>
      <option value="2">Sample Category 2</option>
      <option value="3">Sample Category 3</option>
      <option value="4">Sample Category 4</option>
      <option value="5">Sample Category 5</option>
    </select>
    <label for="choose_exam">Exam List</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="js-datepicker form-control" type="text" name="t_exam"
      id="t_exam" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
    <label for="t_exam">Date</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default add-more pull-right" type="button">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I could help you @newLearner 

Answer (score 0):

So i prefer to discuss about your question under this answer, because i still feel something is wrong, it's not clear to me what you want to do exactly, but here is you can get `#t_exam` and `#choose_exam` value after click on add button. Also it dynamically add selected values to your `html` but with a little changes.

```js
$(".js-datepicker").datepicker();

$(".add-more").click(function() {

  var selectedExam = $('#choose_exam option:selected').val();
  var selectedDate = $('#t_exam').val();

  var html = '<div class="control-group">'+
  '<div class="form-group">'+
  '<div class="exam" name="exam[]">'+selectedExam+'</div>'+
  '<div class="exam_date" name="exam_date[]">'+selectedDate+'</div></div>'+
  '<div class="form-group">'+
  '<button class="btn btn-default remove pull-right" type="button">Delete</button>'+
  '</div></div>'
  ;
  
  $("#copy-fields").append(html);
 // $('.js-datepicker').datepicker('update');
});

//remove button 
$("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
  $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- This is the form contain dropdown menu and datepicker textbox -->
<div class="tab-pane push-30-t push-50" id="validation-step2">

  <div class="form-group">

    <select class="form-control" name="choose_exam[]" id="choose_exam">
    
<!--<?php 
$sql = "Select name from exam_list order by id asc";
$result    = mysql_query( $sql );
while(list($category) = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
$option = '<option value="'.$category.'">'.$category.'</option>';
echo ($option);}
?>-->
    
      <option value="0">Please choose</option>
      <option value="1">Sample Category 1</option>
      <option value="2">Sample Category 2</option>
      <option value="3">Sample Category 3</option>
      <option value="4">Sample Category 4</option>
      <option value="5">Sample Category 5</option>
          </select>

    <label for="choose_exam">Exam List</label>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="js-datepicker form-control" type="text" name="t_exam" id="t_exam" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
    <label for="t_exam">Date</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default add-more pull-right" type="button">Add</button>
  </div>

  <!-- This is for dynamically add every div contains exam and date value upon clicking add button -->

  <div class="copy-fields hide" id="copy-fields"></div>
```

Comment: Downvotes without caring to explain why? It's lame. This is a good attempt at answering a badly asked question (which by the way is not worth the attempt).

Comment: @MajidFouladpour It's ordinary on stackoverflow.. some people like to push the downvote button unreasonable.. I attempted to improve the question first with many edit, then on answer too. but No matter, I don't care about Rep, just want to help other.

Comment: Thank you sir. I appreciate your answer. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: That's good spirit. Still, the importance of asking questions clearly cannot be stressed enough. Q&A on SO are not for the benefit of the OP only; a good question (and the answers it receives) will help many people with similar problems who will find it by searching.